# Unrecognized expression jquery in id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$("#1_0xr__abcdef@gmail.net__ikhhh@gmail.net__054gg")`

giving me Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression 1_0xr__abcdef@gmail.net__ikhhh@gmail.net__054gg

while it is accessible through
`document.getElementById("1_0xr__abcdef@gmail.net__ikhhh@gmail.net__054gg")`

why it is happening so and this id is dynamically get generated through App.

please provide me reason for this problem

Comment: probably the . (dot) makes the problem. Since it is class selector

Comment: after removing dot as well .. it is giving me same error

Answer (score 2):

> From [the doc](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

Below is how you'd write your selector.

```
$("#1_0xr__abcdef\\@gmail\\.net__ikhhh\\@gmail\\.net__054gg")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/djpt7oh3/)

Comment: Thanks @LShetty understood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

escape the special characters . and @ using \\